# Rails REST API - Uninitiallized constant Api error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Created a new project using the command `rails-api new my-api`. Then created a user controller and added the following code in the routes.rb file.

```
namespace :api, defaults:{format:'json'} do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :user
      end
    end
```

user_controller.rb:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class UserController < ApplicationController
        def index

        end
        end
    end
end
```

GemFile:

```
gem 'rails-api'
```

When i tried hitting the URL - "localhost:3000/api/v1/user/" from REST Console or from the browser i got the following error.

```
**Routing Error : uninitialized constant Api**
```

How to fix the error ?

Comment: Your controller class name should be `UsersController` not `UserController`.Try changing it to `UsersController`

Comment: Please show your routes code.. Have you added the API in routes?

Comment: resources :user should be resources :users (plural)

Comment: routes code :                                 MyApi::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
 namespace :api, defaults:{format:'json'} do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :user
      end
    end

Answer (score 0):

First you wrong route, do as below:

```
 scope module: :api, as: :api, format: 'json' do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
```

Next about controllers:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        .....
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And last you need right folder structure like:

[image]

Comment: In the controller do i need to remove the module Api and module V1 ?

Comment: Added the given code in routes file and also in the Usercontroller and then moved the usercontroller and appcontroller to controllers/api/v1 folder. Now i am getting 
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController

Comment: and you need restart server.

Comment: yes that is a typo. But even now i am getting the same error

Comment: class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController. I removed the Api::V1 and added module Api module V1 .... end now it works. Thank you !

Comment: @user2883376 this the same thing ) approve answer if i help.